# Swagger doesnt detect in command from makefile ubuntu 22

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-22.04, go-swagger

i have install swagger in my computer, and i try to run my swagger command using makefile to validate my go project in linux 22 but the swagger doesn't detect
[image]

if i try to run the swagger direcly from terminal its work
[image]

for information my make version is 4.3 and i put the makefile file in the directory ~/Program/Mediverse/bionews

[image]

anyone give me advice so i can use swagger command or other in makefile, thanks

Comment: Did you try opening a new terminal tab and see if the swagger command is still working?

Comment: Also try @swagger validate…

Comment: Please, do not show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Moreover they affect accessibility negatively. Please copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.